# Angular 5 Reactive Forms - multiple forms in one view template

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

My idea is to support multiple forms on one view template, and then show only the one I need accordingly to user interaction.

For starters, I have a HOST node and a LOCATION node - both under one `[formGroup]` - then I show/hide as needed.

Problem is that my HOST form is ALWAYS showing an `INVALID` status - even when I touch it. However, my LOCATION form is `VALID` once I "touch" it. This is the confusing part.

Here's a snippet:

```html
<form class="popup-dialog form-horizontal" [formGroup]="nodeEditForm" (ngSubmit)="updateNode(nodeEditForm.value)"> 

 <!-- LOCATION -->
 <table [hidden]="nodeType != 'Location'" class="table table-bordered location-node">
  <!-- all location form controls here... -->
 </table>

 <!-- HOST -->
 <table [hidden]="nodeType != 'Host'" class="table table-bordered host-node">
  <!-- all location form controls here... -->
 </table>

 <p>Form value: {{ nodeEditForm.value | json }}</p>
 <p>Form status: {{ nodeEditForm.status | json }} &nbsp; Dirty: {{ nodeEditForm.dirty}} &nbsp; Touched: {{ nodeEditForm.touched}}</p>
  
      <!-- SAVE/CANCEL -->
 <div class="buttons">
  <div style="display: inline;" role-required="Admin" edit-access="true">
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" [disabled]="!nodeEditForm.valid || !nodeEditForm.dirty" (click)="updateNode($event)">
    <span *ngIf="!isUpdating" >SAVE</span>
    <i *ngIf="isUpdating" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
   </button>
  </div>

  <div style="display: inline;">
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="clearNode($event)" >Cancel</button>
  </div>            
 </div>
</form>
```

And in my Angular component:

```js
// OnChanges fired first, this.node will be null
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){       
  if(changes["node"] != null){
     this.currPage = 1;
     this.initNode();  // all props get assigned empty default values
     this.initForm();
   }
}

initForm() {            
  let grp = this.getFormData(this.node);

  // ADD GROUP CONTROLS FOR FORM !!
  this.nodeEditForm = this.nodeFormBldr.group(grp);

  return;
}

// Assign node properties to form controls; properties initialized in initNode()
  getFormData(node: INode) {

    //this.editXml(); // TO DO     

    return {        
      LocationName: [this.node.LocationName : '', Validators.required],
      LocationType: [this.node.LocationType],
      Address1: [this.node.Address1],
      Address2: [this.node.Address2],
      City: [this.node.City],
      State: [this.node.State],
      Country: [this.node.Country],
      ZipCode: [this.node.ZipCode],
      Phone: [this.node.Phone],
      Email: [this.node.Email],

      ApplicationRoot: [this.hostNode.ApplicationRoot],
      DefaultHostStorage: [this.hostNode.DefaultHostStorage],
      HostName: [this.hostNode.HostName],
      HostIp: [this.hostNode.HostIP],
      IsActive: [this.hostNode.IsActive],        
      XmlData: [this.hostNode.xmlConfig]
    }    
  }
```

Comment: I bet your HostName form doesn't set the LocationName field. And thus its always invalid as you have `Validators.required` set for the LocationName.

Comment: @user3492940 -good point. It could be my problem.

Comment: I'm wondering if I should just play it safe and create a different `[formGroup]` for each 'node' type I will need to edit. i.e. There are other node types I will need to deal with very soon, not just Location and Host.

Comment: In your situation I would do that for sure. It doesn't make any sense to have the same form to be used for different data sets.

Comment: @user3492940 - add your answer because you found my specific problem. Thank you for the extra advice as well. Separate forms seems to be the best practice here.

Comment: Glad it's fixed and you found the help useful! I added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet your HostName form doesn't set the LocationName field. And thus its always invalid as you have Validators.required set for the LocationName.